# Splitting Object into two different objects using a script

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I am splitting an object into two. I am able to do it using the GUI. I go to edit mode, select the vertices I want, then press <kbd>P</kbd> and select partition by selection. Can anyone help me with the equivalent in script of pressing <kbd>P</kbd> and making the partition by selection. (Not able to find the command in the info window during the operation)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Its `bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a script I made to split by vertex color. It uses the bpy.ops.mesh.seperate() method as described in another answer. The bulk of it is figuring out what to seperate, but you asked for an example script, so here is one from my toolbox.

```
'''SPLIT MESH BY VERTEX COLOUR

Script written by sdfgeoff, Jan 2016
Licensed under GPL, share what you make.'''

import bpy
import mathutils

def splitNextColor(obj, threshold=0.01):
    def getPolyColor(p):
        '''Returns the average colour of a face'''
        colors = obj.data.vertex_colors.active.data
        r = g = b = 0
        for i in p.loop_indices:
            c = colors[i].color
            r += c.r
            g += c.g
            b += c.b
        r /= p.loop_total
        g /= p.loop_total
        b /= p.loop_total
        return mathutils.Vector((r, g, b)) #So we can compare colors using the .length operator 

    #Pick the first polygon
    p = obj.data.polygons[0]
    target = getPolyColor(p)

    for p in obj.data.polygons:
        source = getPolyColor(p)

        #Select any polygons that are similar in colour
        if (source - target).length < threshold:
            p.select = True
        else:
            p.select = False

    #Seperate the selected faces
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED')
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()



#Get the current object
obj = bpy.context.active_object

selectList = []
if obj.data.vertex_colors.active == None:
    print("Object does not have vertex colors")
else:
    #Split of colours until there are no face left
    while(len(obj.data.polygons) > 0):
        splitNextColor(obj)

    #Delete the no-polygon object that:
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if ob != obj:
            ob.select = False
            selectList.append(ob)
        else:
            ob.select = True

    bpy.ops.object.delete()

    for ob in selectList:
        ob.select = True
```